# How do I remove header/page-title image in farvis theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, custom-header, header-image

I'm working with farvis theme. In that theme I removed background image in customize >> page titles & Breadcrumbs >> background image >> remove. But after I clicked save and reloaded the site another image is showing on screen in header image, I didn't find that image in Media Library.

Why this happening after removing header image in theme option. Tell me any additional CSS code to solve this problem.

Here is my screen shots. My desktop view
[image]
If you can observe that image in between slider and menu there is an image. I want to remove that.
                      [image: My mobile view]

Here's the mobile view.
Please tell me solution for this ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: You can hide that image div using css like `display:none;`

Comment: When do I add this code? @PratikPatel

Comment: Please share full CSS code.

Comment: Please share your site link so i can create css as per div

Comment: http://www.odishahues.com/ ---> Here's my site link.

Comment: I have added answer so please check and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below CSS end of your theme `style.css` file

> wp-content/themes/farvis/style.css

```
section.header-section {
background-image: none !important;
}
```

Please try and let me know if any query.

Updated
[image]

Comment: Not working. I added code at last of the page in style.css

Comment: Please try to hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) page, bcoz my side image is gone

Comment: I refreshed my page 5 times and it's not gone. Please tell me other solution

Comment: @Anudeepsyamprasad Please check above updated answer, I have add updated screen shot of site and header image is not showing now , So please check once in Private browser

Comment: But it's showing white space in mobile view. Please resize the window. So you will know the problem.

Comment: Open your **wp-content/themes/farvis/css/responsive.css** file , Go to line number **1297** and replace **padding-top: 150px !important;** To **padding-top: 0px !important;** and check again in mobile view

Comment: If this answer is use-full for u then please mark as a accepted and rate this. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot rate because I'm new to this wordpress forum. I don't have good reputation. Surely I will rate it later/future.. Thanks